# Image rotation issue in camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2

I've refered to the the google sample for camera2 api. On most of the devices it works fine but on nokia 6.1 everytime i click a portrait mode and show it on image view it is being shown as landscape.

i tried

```
private int getOrientation(int rotation) {
    // Sensor orientation is 90 for most devices, or 270 for some devices (eg. Nexus 5X)
    // We have to take that into account and rotate JPEG properly.
    // For devices with orientation of 90, we simply return our mapping from ORIENTATIONS.
    // For devices with orientation of 270, we need to rotate the JPEG 180 degrees.
    return (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + mSensorOrientation + 270) % 360;
}
```

as well as

```
private int getJpegOrientation(CameraCharacteristics c, int deviceOrientation) {
    if (deviceOrientation == android.view.OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return 0;
    int sensorOrientation = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);

    // Round device orientation to a multiple of 90
    deviceOrientation = (deviceOrientation + 45) / 90 * 90;

    // Reverse device orientation for front-facing cameras
    boolean facingFront = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
    if (facingFront) deviceOrientation = -deviceOrientation;

    // Calculate desired JPEG orientation relative to camera orientation to make
    // the image upright relative to the device orientation
    int jpegOrientation = (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;

    return jpegOrientation;
}
```

for setting JPEG_ORIENTATION in CaptureRequest.Builder , but none of them worked for me

values i am getting from both the methods is 90 but that doesn't affects the jpeg file in any way. whereas for similar results on nokia 1 and xiomi note 4 jpeg file produced is correct (i.e. while clicking a portrait image, portrait jpeg is saved in file system)

PS:- Nokia 6.1 is an Android One Device(If that has something to do with erroneous results)

Comment: Well tell exactly which values for orientation you get. Give full info.Also tell which values you expect normally. Show where and how you call those functions and with which parameter values. Please adapt your post. Write a clear story. Which Android version?

Comment: Please explain what your complaint is. You show two methods that are expected to return **jpegOrientation**: 90º, 0º, or whatever. On the problematic Nokia 6.1, do both give wrong results? Or do you mean that you tried to set JPEG_ORIENTATION with CaptureRequest.Builder, and this did not produce the expected Jpeg file? Or did you mean that you could not display this Jpeg file correctly on ImageView?